# AngularJS model tracking?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
var ticket = angular.module('ticket', []);

ticket.controller('ticketCtrl', function($scope, $http){
$scope.ticketQty = 1;
  
  
  
  
  $scope.envoyer = function(){


alert('Sending no :'+ $scope.ticketQty);

}
  
  
  });//Ctrl
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ticket" ng-controller="ticketCtrl">
    <input ng-model="ticketQty" type="number" class="form-control" size="5">
  
  <button ng-click="envoyer()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Envoyer</button>
</div>
```

I have a variable in angular that is declared like that :

```
$scope.var = 1;
```

and a model :

```
<input ng-model="var" type="number" class="form-control">
```

So when I type in 4 the app is working fine interpreting the number but if  I refer to $scope.var in a function send for exemple :

```
$scope.send = function(){
alert($scope.var);
}
```

I get 1 as a result;

Why am I not getting 4?

Comment: Better not name your variable like a reserved keyword, it could have strange effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap this up inside an object like this

```
$scope.var = {
num: ""
}
```

then use it like this in the input tag

```
<input ng-model="var.num" type="number" class="form-control">
```

this should work fine